# How to trigger a svg animation(html) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jquery-animate

I am animating a rect in html/svg. I have also created a function in javascript and I would like the animation to begin only when the function is called.

here's my code:

```
<svg>
<rect onclick="rightSide()" id="rightGreen" x="512" y="0" width="100%" height="768" fill="black" display="block">
       <animate id="openright"
                   attributeName="x"
                   from="512"
                   to="1536"
                   dur="5.5s"
                   repeatCount="1"
                   begin="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Everything works fine, however i need it to start when a function is called.?

Answer (score 1):

You call `beginElement()` on the `<animate>` element object.

```
document.getElementById("openright").beginElement()
```